# Change text colour to background colour with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using Wordpress editor to change text colour, is there a way I can then use jquery to force it to make this the background colour instead.

This is what wp renders when I change the colour of the text:

```
<p>
   <span style="color: #ff0000;">
      <a style="color: #ff0000;" href="#">Link name</a>
   </span>
</p>
```

I want the background to be whatever colour I choose instead.

Something along the lines of, but I'm stuck.
[THE SELECTED COLOUR] is just a placeholder so you can see what I'm trying to do.

```
$("p span a").css("background-color","[THE SELECTED COLOUR]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, where you iterate though them all

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   <span style="color: #ff0000;">
      <a style="color: #ff0000;" href="#">Link name</a>
   </span>
</p>
<p>
   <span style="color: #0000ff;">
      <a style="color: #0000ff;" href="#">Link name</a>
   </span>
</p>
<script>
  $("p span a").each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).css("background-color", $( this ).css("color"));
    $( this ).css("color", "white");
  });
</script>
```

Or, as A.Wollf suggests in his comment, use a `function`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   <span style="color: #ff0000;">
      <a style="color: #ff0000;" href="#">Link name</a>
   </span>
</p>
<p>
   <span style="color: #0000ff;">
      <a style="color: #0000ff;" href="#">Link name</a>
   </span>
</p>
<script>
  $("p span a").css({"background-color":function(){ return $(this).css('color'); }, "color": "white"});
</script>
```

Comment: Work only for one element or if all have same color. `css()` method accepts a fucntion that should be used here, e.g: `$("p span a").css("background-color",function(){
    return $(this).css('color');
});`. But you still need to reset the color (not background one), otherwise, no way to read anchor text

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect as I need several colour styles going on.

Comment: @A.Wolff Updated my answer

Comment: Actually. How could I then make the text colour itself white?

Comment: @xhadf Updated my answer

Comment: @A.Wolff Added a 2:nd sample using a function, which does reset the color as well

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful

```
$("p span a").css("background-color","green");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pbszus12/)